# How do you calculate the energy released by a gas spring when it is released from being fully compressed?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, robotics

I'm a Freshman Mech E Student, and I'm designing a 3lb Combat Robot for a club. I wanted to be weird and use something I've never seen on a bot before. It's a fun design challenge, but physics calculations are where I struggle most...

Basically, I want to charge up a gas spring with a motor and release it to rotate my spear into the vitals of another robot. I want to know if it could at least damage another robot, or if the energy released is not significant enough. I think its nice that the spring can do 100 cycles per minute, which means my robot could stab a robot 100 times per minute if I design it right.

How do you calculate the energy released by the spring, and how do you calculate how much force it takes to charge up the spring by a certain amount? Are these values the same?

Even if it's entirely not worth it to use a spring like this, I want to at least be able to calculate why, but I don't even know where to begin with that. I can't find any examples online of people using gas springs like I'm trying to, and I've also struggled to calculate the work/energy released depending on how much you compress the spring.

I've seen some approaches that use integration and the area of the cross section of the spring, but I don't know which to apply here.

I know that for a normal compression spring, the Work/PE = 1/2 * kd^2, but I'm not sure of how to calculate the k factor for a gas spring.

I attached an image with some questions I've thought of, as well as a [GIF of what the range of motion looks like](https://imgur.com/a/wNzXV1W) (Its not NSFW, its literally the CAD of my robot, Imgur is silly).

[Gas Spring I selected from McMaster](https://www.mcmaster.com/6643K74-6643K444/)

Gas Spring Info

Extended Length: 4.65"

Compressed Length: 3.15"

Stroke Length: 1.5"

Extension force: 164 lbs

Compression force: 112 lbs

Rod diameter: 0.24"

I presumed these kind of springs would be a decent choice because they are "high force" and are used for stamping/die-spring applications.

I still am not entirely sure what the difference between compression and extension force is. I could be wrong, but I think the extension force is the amount of force that it is exerting in its unloaded state, and the compression force is how much force it takes to compress it to its fully compressed state.

Any thoughts or advice you have would seriously help! If there is a better place to defer my question to, also please let me know. I have been trying to wrap my head around this for over a week now. If you have any questions or need elaboration on my ideas, feel free to ask :)

Thank you for reading!

Also: made this gas spring motion simulator in Desmos, would be cool if I could add force/work calculations into it: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lrp2jtafxl
[image: The layout of my spring/spear setup and some questions]

[image: (Incomplete) Robot render for reference]